# PyRal: How to change a Service Account password in Rally using pyral?

Tags: python, pyral

I have a Rally Service Account whose password expired every three months, and we are currently changing it manually.

I'd like to update the password with automation using PyRal (if possible.)

I can get the account's info like this:

```
import sys
from pyral import Rally, rallyWorkset

server = "rally1.rallydev.com"
user = "svc_acct"
password = "pass1"
workspace = "MyWksp"
project = "MyProj"
rally = Rally(server, user, password, workspace=workspace, project=project)

userinf=rally.getUserInfo(username=user)
```

But I'm not seeing any function available to change the password.

Can this be done using pyral?

If so, what call do I have to make?

Have searched around and not found anything online either.

Thanks!